# Already loggedin middleware slim php

Tags: php, authentication, middleware, slim

Okay I created this small authentication middleware to prevent access to private routes in my slim application:

```
$authenticate = function($app) {
    return function() use ($app) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            $errors = array();
            $errors['authentication'] = 'Login Required';
            $app->flash('error', $errors);
            $app->redirect('/login');
        }
    };
};
```

Now I want to prevent the user to be able to go to the login route ('/login') once the user has already been authenticated?

Should I create another middleware like so:

```
$loggedIn = function($app) {
    return function() use ($app) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            $app->redirect('/members');
        }
    };
};
```

And add it here:

```
$app->get('/login', $loggedIn($app), function() use ($app){
   // something in here.
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep logged in users from hitting the `/login` route, you can just use one of the route helpers to redirect them to an appropriate end point (maybe their account/user detail page or something like that if you have one):

```
$app->get('/login', function () use ($app) {
    if (isLoggedIn()) {
        $app->redirect('/account');
    }
    else {
        // your standard login code here
    }
});
```

I think that makes more sense than writing an isLoggedIn middleware.